# How to put data from List<string []> to dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, datagridview

Try to put some data from List to dataGridView, but have some problem with it.

Currently have method, that return me required List  - please see picture below

code

```
    public List<string[]> ReadFromFileBooks()
    {
        List<string> myIdCollection = new List<string>();
        List<string[]> resultColl = new List<string[]>();
        if (chooise == "all")
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {                        
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
                    string[] line = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    foreach (string l in line)
                    {
                        string[] result = l.Split(',');
                        foreach (string element in result)
                        {
                            myIdCollection.Add(element);
                        }
                        resultColl.Add(new string[] { myIdCollection[0], myIdCollection[1], myIdCollection[2], myIdCollection[3] });
                        myIdCollection.Clear();
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                    return resultColl;
                }
            }
     ....
```

this return to me required data in requred form (like list from arrays).
[image]

After this, try to move it to the dataGridView, that already have 4 columns with names (because i'm sure, that no than 4 colums required) - please see pic below

[image]

Try to put data in to dataGridView using next code

```
    private void radioButtonViewAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TxtLibrary myList = new TxtLibrary(filePathBooks);
        myList.chooise = "all";
        //myList.ReadFromFileBooks();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (var array in myList.ReadFromFileBooks())
        {
            table.Rows.Add(array);
        }
        dataGridViewLibrary.DataSource = table;
    }
```

But as result got error - "required more rows that exist in dataGridVIew", but accordint to what I'm see (pic above) q-ty of rows (4) equal q-ty of arrays element in List (4).

Try to check result by putting additional temp variables - but it's ok - please see pic below

[image]

Where I'm wrong? Maybe i use dataGridView not in correct way?

**EDIT**

example of file (simple csv)

11111, Author, Name, Categories

11341, Author1, Name1, Categories1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **add columns** to your `DataTable` first before adding rows:

```
private void radioButtonViewAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TxtLibrary myList = new TxtLibrary(filePathBooks);
    myList.chooise = "all";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    //add columns first
    table.Columns.Add("ID");
    table.Columns.Add("Author");
    table.Columns.Add("Caption");
    table.Columns.Add("Categories");
    //then add rows
    foreach (var array in myList.ReadFromFileBooks()) {
        table.Rows.Add(array);
    }
    dataGridViewLibrary.DataSource = table;
}
```

Comment: it's work perfect, so as I unerstand structure of dataGridView can't be used with DataSourse that configured partially? or exist some way to do this? Means if I create colums in FormConstructor can i create just row   in code or anyway i must to create colums in code ?

Comment: @Kirill the point is **before adding rows to a DataTable, it must have at least 1 column, in other words, it should have some table structure first before adding rows**. You don't need to add columns to your `DataGridView` manually, when you assign `dataGridViewLibrary.DataSource = table`, your `Gridview` will automatically generate the corresponding columns (AutoGenerateColumns=true).

Comment: @Kirill if the answer solved your problem, you should click on the V-shaped tick to accept the answer, that would be your best thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I think your code it's too complex. SImply, if you want see all data in the table from the file, you can do this

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists("file.txt"))
            return;
        dgvDataGridView.ColumnCount = 4;
        dgvDataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "ID";
        dgvDataGridView.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "Author";
        dgvDataGridView.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "Caption";
        dgvDataGridView.Columns[3].HeaderCell.Value = "Categories";
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("file.txt"))
            while (sr.Peek() > -1)
                dgvDataGridView.Rows.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split(','));
```